# how can i read @Pathvariable name and value using HandlerInterceptor in spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor

My code is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "productDescription/{productId}/{competitorList}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ProductDescription getProductDescription(
        @PathVariable String productId, @PathVariable String competitorList) {
    return service.getProductDescription(productId, competitorList);
}
```

Using `HttpServletRequest` request in postHandler method, I want to read the pathvariable names and values.

I am able to get parameter name and values using request.getParameterMap() method if I'm using @RequestParam instead @Pathvariable.

Comment: PathVariable is spring's feature. not accessible in HttpServletRequest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "productDescription/{productId}/{competitorList}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ProductDescription getProductDescription(@PathVariable("productId") String productId, @PathVariable("competitorList") String competitorList) {
    return service.getProductDescription(productId, competitorList);
}
```